# In jquery: Use attr("class") value as a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have fields with multiple classes. I want to use one of those classes as a selector, how do I do this?

generic example:

```
<input id="from"/><div class="error from">errormessage</div>
<input id="to"/>
<div><input id="when" /></div><div class="error when">errormessage</div>
```

Because ther is a div.error with the class from, I want to add a certain class to input#from and the same goes for the input called when. Note that "when" is wrapped in a div. Several variations like this are necessary for the page. Therefore, tree-traversal is not a suitable solution.

Comment: Do you mean `$('stuff.class')`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*For updated question:*

I *think* this is what you're after, since the element since to be a previous sibling or contained in one:

```
$(".error").prev().find("input").andSelf().filter("input").addClass("test");
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uGCeR/).

---

*For previous question:*
Use the [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
$(".myCass")
```

You can also select elements that only have *multiple* classes by chaining them, for example:

```
$(".myCass.myClass2.myClass3")
```

Would only select elements that had **all 3** classes.

Comment: Ideally with tag prefixed $("span.myclass")

Comment: @Sam - It depends on the browser, but yes for older browsers this will help performance, given you know the element type.

Comment: @Sam, or not, if you want to target multiple elements (*tags*) with the same class.. depends on context.. plus it would be slower if the browser supports the `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: If you already have a wrapped selection, you can use .hasclass('classname') to return true or false on that selection depending on if it's been assigned the class.  $('.classname') is the very basic class selector though, a bread-and-butter kind of jQuery tool.

Comment: @Kristoffer - check out the updated answer, is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors are nothing but strings, HTML attributes are nothing but strings and regular JavaScript has string operators and functions.

Here's a little (and meaningless) code snippet that puts these ideas together:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css"><!--
--></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($){
    $("div").css({border: "1px solid black"}).each(function(){
        var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
        for(var i=0, len=classes.length; i<len; i++){
            $("." + classes[i]).append("<p>I have class " + classes[i] + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="foo bar dot">foo bar dot</div>
<div class="bar dot">bar dot</div>
<div class="dot">dot</div>


</body>
</html>
```

It's nice as a proof of concept, but you should double-check that your design is the simplest one.