# In jquery: Use attr(“class”) value as a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In jquery: Use attr(“class”) value as a selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096834/in-jquery-use-attrclass-value-as-a-selector)

I have fields with multiple classes. I want to use one of those classes as a selector, how do I do this?

generic example:

```
<input id="from"/><div class="error from">errormessage</div>
<input id="to"/>
<div><input id="when" /></div><div class="error when">errormessage</div>
```

Because ther is a div.error with the class from, I want to add a certain class to input#from and the same goes for the input called when.
Note that "when" is wrapped in a div. Several variations like this are necessary for the page. Therefore, tree-traversal is not a suitable solution.

Comment: I do not understand. What do you mean by "use as a selector"? In jQuery?

Comment: Are you referring to .hasClass()? http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Definitely looks like a dupe, question with same name, same poster, and same question.

Comment: whoops, duplicate somehow, anyways: See edit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098458/in-jquery-use-attrclass-value-as-a-selector

Comment: You want to apply a class to `.from` and `.when` *if* they both *also* contain the class `.error`?

Comment: no, if the error div exists, I wanna get the "from"-value (or whatever that next value is, find an input with that value, and add MyClass as a class to that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.error.from')
```

or

```
$('.from.error')
```

Note the **lack** of white-space between the two class-names `.error` and `.from`, which selects only those elements with **both** of the given class-names.

If there *had* been a space (`$('.error .from')`) then this would select an element of class `from` that is a descendant of an element of class `.error`.

You could, if you wanted to (though I can't think why you would), use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
$('.error').hasClass('from');
```

Though I think this is rather less efficient.

Comment: You misunderstood, see my clairification here: See edit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098458/in-jquery-use-attrclass-value-as-a-selector